# In bash, how can I get a URL from a markup file without using regex lookarounds?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, regex-lookarounds

I want to grep the URL out of a .asx file. The file would normally look like this.

```
<ASX VERSION="3.0">
<ENTRY>
<TITLE>Blah Blah</TITLE>
<AUTHOR>Someone</AUTHOR>
<COPYRIGHT>（C）2014 Someone Else</COPYRIGHT>
<REF HREF="mms://www.example.com/video/FilmName/FilmName.wmv"/>
</ENTRY>
</ASX>
```

I want to get the URL without the quotes, and stripping off the mms://

I came up with a regex that uses lookarounds that does this successfully:

```
((?<=\/\/).*?).(?=\")
```

but of course I can't use this with grep. So what is another approach that would be flexible to capture whatever comes between the mms:// and the " that I could put into a grep -o command?

Comment: Of course, [don't use regex to parse XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `but of course I can't use this with grep.`

Why not? Modern grep versions supports `-P` switch for PCRE regex support.

Try this:

```
grep -oP '((?<=//).*?).(?=")' file
www.example.com/video/FilmName/FilmName.wmv
```

Comment: Wouldn't `'(?<=://)[^"]+'` be sufficient for this?

Comment: Oh yes `grep -oP '(?<=://).*?(?=")'` would be fine too, I just used OP's regex.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for correcting it, point well taken, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
awk -F '[:"]' '/REF HREF/ {print substr($3,3)}' file
www.example.com/video/FilmName/FilmName.wmv
```

Comment: Nice; perhaps `awk -F '[:"]' '/REF HREF/ {print substr($3,3)}' file` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

With BASH, you can use the left/right pattern matching:

```
url='<REF HREF="mms://www.example.com/video/FilmName/FilmName.wmv"/>'
url=${url#<REF HREF=\"}
url=${url%\"/>}
echo "URL is '$url'"   # Prints URL is 'mms://www.example.com/video/FilmName/FilmName.wmv'
```

`${VAR#pattern}` strips off of `$VAR` the shortest left hand side glob that matches `pattern`. `${VAR##pattern}`strips off of `$var` the largest left hand side glob that matches `pattern`. And, `${VAR%pattern}` and `${VAR%pattern}` do the same for the right hand side of `$VAR`.

An easy way to remember is that `#` is to the *left* of `%` on the keyboard. [David Korn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Korn_%28computer_scientist%29) taught me that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for OSX users, where `grep` (as of OSX 10.9) doesn't support `-P` and look-arounds are therefore not an option:

```
egrep -o '"[a-z]+://[^"]+' file | cut -d '/' -f 3-
```